# Android double variable calculation is crashing application

Tags: java, android, calculator

I am new at android app development and just for fun, I am trying to create calculator app with custom keyboard. I got almost all functionality working in my app. Just the final step is not working.

So when I try to calculate with +, -, * or / the final string I get would look like

1 + 2 * 3 / 1 - 2 (actually in string format)

and I am storing this in variable by converting

double d = new Double(string "1 + 2 * 3 / 1 - 2")

if I just print out with normal java, `System.out.println(d);`

I get "5.0" as answer. I don't mind with this answer. But when I try to print out with following codes,

```
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.cal_EQ)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){



 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {


if(inputKB.getText().toString() != null && inputKB.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
   calcDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(new Double((inputKB.getText().toString()))));
                }
            }
        });
```

its crashing the app. So what should I do to get result like 5.0 and display it to scree?

Thanx for your time and help in advance. ;)

```
02-10 19:18:46.789  29734-29734/io.github.xyz.calc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.github.xyz.calc, PID: 29734
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "5 + 5"
            at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
            at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:269)
            at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
            at java.lang.Double.<init>(Double.java:136)
            at io.github.xyz.calc.RegCalcActivity$7.onClick(RegCalcActivity.java:118)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4480)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18686)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-10 19:18:49.002  29734-29734/io.github.xyz.calc D/Process﹕ killProcess, pid=29734
02-10 19:18:49.002  29734-29734/io.github.xyz.calc D/Process﹕ com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:131 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690
02-10 19:18:49.352  30138-30138/io.github.xyz.calc I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: MINGHSUC_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.047+PATCH[ES]_msm8960_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.047__release_ENGG ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.12.SPL
```

This is logcat error log and line 118 is

```
calcDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(new Double((inputKB.getText().toString()))));
```

Thanx ;)

Comment: as you can see `"5 + 5"` is not valid number

Comment: So what should I do then? caz you can see I am converting string to double so.

Answer (score 0):

Math is not explicitly supported in the String constructor, so this will be JRE dependent. It's not surprising that the Android JRE would strip out any code that supports undocumented features. There are 3rd party libraries such as JEval, MVEL or Jep (licensed).

Answer (score 0):

you could try this by adding bracket in starting and end

```
calcDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(new Double(("("+inputKB.getText().toString()+")"))));
```